# avconv version 9.14 streaming video (using UV4L driver RaspiCam) and video (using ALSA) to ustream, no audio

Tags: alsa, streaming, ffmpeg, v4l2

I'm using avconv to read from `/dev/video0` (which is attached to my RPi camera via UV4L) and also reading audio from my [microphone](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B004P1BQG2) using ALSA and stream it live on [ustream.tv](http://www.ustream.tv/). It works just fine to stream video to ustream, but when I add audio I can't hear anything at all.

This is the command I use to stream:

```
avconv -f alsa -i plughw:1,0 -f video4linux2 -s 320x240 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -r 25 -f flv rtmp://*STREAM URL/STREAM KEY*
```

My issue is that I can't hear anything through the livestream, but the video works fine.

Comment: I take it the microphone works fine to record wav files on the Pi normally?

Comment: @rob Yes it works fine using `arecord -D plughw:1,0 -f cd test.wav`